# Defect in DatastoreIO - Read kind within a namespace

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What steps will reproduce the problem?

Add a DatastoreIO read operation for a kind within a specific namespace.  Size estimation and subsequent split algorithm using datastore system stats table is failing.

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

**DatastoreIO.queryLatestStatisticsTimestamp** us using the system table "**Stat_Total**" to retrieve the timestamp for the latest stats run.  The method is leveraging a common method **DatastoreIO.makeRequest**, which is applying the namespace of the kind being read.  Because "**Stat_Total**" resides in the default namespace, nothing is returned resulting in an error that stats cannot be read for the kind.  DatastoreIO falls back to using the number of workers to split the query, which is not ideal in our case.  This appears to be a defect.  The namespace should not be applied to the query to retrieve stats.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
Version 1.6 / Default GCE Dataflow Service VMs

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting the problem. You are right, we need to use "**Stat_Ns_Total**" when namespace is provided. I will submit a fix and it should be available in the next release (1.7.0)

Update: This has been fixed and released in [1.7.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java#170)